# What UI component can I use to make login page a switch tab as shown in the picture

Tags: html, uiview, material-design

[Does anybody know what kind of UI component in Angular material which can implement this? When a user login a correct username it can switch to the next tab..it looks like a tab but I just checked out material tab it is different. Thank you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRwpM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You use angular material https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview
and customize you login on the basis of your requirement, like if user successfully login then on the next tab etc.